# Which Linux source code to download

Tags: linux-kernel

I am new to kernel development. Currently I am running Ubuntu 13.04. My current kernel is 3.8.0-23-generic.

My question is, do I need to install exact 3.8.0-23-generic source code to do development and see the results?

Comment: This should be on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No, **as the text literally mentions** this is a *development* question, and belongs here.

Comment: @ChrisStratton- ok, I thought so.. No offense meant

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, to obtain the source for the currently running kernel you can use the command below:

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

See [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/SourceCode) for detail.

Answer (score 1):

There are detailed instructions for building a kernel in Ubuntu here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept called **kernel version magic** which ensures the correct version of module is inserted in to kernel always. so you need to install exact 3.8.0-23-generic source code for inserting your modules.

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x380.html for some guidance about version magic.

Suppose you want to do development only in 2.6.X, then simply download that 2.6.x from kernel.org and follow the link http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html